# When was The Sound of Music first released on VHS

Tags: distribution, the-sound-of-music

I've read that it could have been one of the 1st 3 movies to be released on VHS in 1977.  Can anyone verify this?!

Answer (score 2):

From [What was the first movie commercially released on VHS?](http://www.primermagazine.com/2009/field-manual/know-it-all-the-first-movie-commercially-released-on-vhs):

> According to Frederick Wasser’s Veni, Vidi, Video, the **American home
>   video market was essentially born in 1977**, courtesy of an audio/video
>   firm called Magnetic Video. At the time, Twentieth Century Fox was a
>   company struggling through dire financial straits (despite the
>   ridiculously successful May 25th release of a flick called Star Wars)
>   and looking to generate some sort of revenue beyond box office ticket
>   sales. Magnetic’s founder Andre Blay took advantage of these
>   circumstances, paying Fox for the home video licensing rights to fifty
>   of the studio’s films. And with that, a now extremely prominent
>   entertainment market roared to life.
>
> **The first three American flicks released on VHS? The Sound of Music**,
>   Patton, and M*A*S*H (at an average retail cost of $50-$70, each).

Other links also corroborate this. It appears your assertion is correct.